# Individual CSS for resources in ember-cli

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-cli

With ember-cli, css is compiled into the one app.css file.
In my project I have two resources (user and admin) each with their own routes and I want each resource to have its own set of css without being in conflict with the other.
Is there an efficient way of doing this in ember-cli?

Comment: This doesn't help you with your immediate problem, but I personally would recommend against different CSS files based on the user; that'll get too messy too quickly. I think a better way to do it would be to use different CSS classes based on the user which all come from the same file.

Comment: As a single-page application, Ember will load CSS(es) at page load time.  It is up to you to make sure the combined CSS model (regardless of the number of css files in play) works for all your resources.

Comment: Just edited my question to reflect this; I don't necessarily want to use multiple css files. Also, I could just put a selector at the front of most of my css tags and change the code to suit but my team mate believes this to be a bit long and messy so I want a quicker and cleaner method of doing it.